# Is there a way to connect paypal express checkout to a website user account?

Tags: paypal

Example:

I log into mywebsite.com and buy a book (uses PayPal). It asks me to save card information. I save it. Now from now on, every time I log into mywebsite.com, I can buy books fast without filling anything out.

In essence, can I connect a users account on mywebsite.com to a PayPal transaction history to allow for quick checkout for future purchases?

Comment: Yes, several such products. Read the PayPal docs for features like Preapproved Payments, Reference Transactions, Future Payments....

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do that with PayPal, but I would recommend the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) with [Billing Agreements and Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/).